# Debug Flutter app is not working with VSCode on Xiaomi Device

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, debugging, xiaomi

I'm starting developing mobile using flutter on vscode IDE. I was debbuging the app using a samsung device, everything was ok, but I tryed debug the app using a xiaomi device, however this time i've got an error

> Launching lib/main.dart on 166216e0 in debug mode...
> Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
> adb: insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group
> See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
> adb: insufficient permissions for device: missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group
> See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
> Error launching application on 166216e0.
> Exited (sigterm)

There's a difference of android version. Samsung is android 11 and xiaomi is a MIUI Global 12.0.4 android 10.

apart from having usb debug enabled, i've enabled the option to install via usb and usb debugging.

I don't know how to solve this. Any suggestion?

I've updated SDK Manager adding android 10

[image]

after that i runned
flutter doctor --android-licenses
but I still not working

Answer (score 2):

fix would be to set the phone to File Transfer mode or PTP mode.so you have to change it from USB "Charge this phone" to "PTP" (Picture Transfer Protocol).